# Linkedin profile - i have acess token with it can i pull data in other domain

Tags: linkedin-api

I have register my application with LinkedIn and gave  Website URL: `abc.net`

I am able to get access_token and profile information of the user in the `abc.net` which act as an server in our case.  Now I need to send this data to different domains.

In Facebook API, if I send only access_token to other domains ,I am able to fetch data in the other domain using

```
$fb_id_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" . $token;
$fb_info_json = file_get_contents($fb_id_url);
```

Is there any provision like this in Linkedin?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using the [REST API](https://developer.linkedin.com/rest) - in this case, the application is not necessarily tied to a single domain or machine - using the application API keys and the user's OAuth tokens from other domains should work fine.